# Why are integration tests failing on updates to model objects when the function is run on Django q-cluster?

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-unittest

I am running some django integration tests of code that passes some functions to [Django-Q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for processing.  This code essentially updates some fields on a model object.

The app uses `signals.py` to listen for a `post_save` change of the `status` field of the `Foo` object.  Assuming it's not a newly created object and it has the correct status, the `Foo.prepare_foo()` function is called.  This is handled by `services.py` which hands it off to `q-cluster`.  Assuming this executes without error `hooks.py` changes the `status` field of `Foo` to `published`, or keeps it at `prepare` if it fails. If it passes then it also sets `prepared` to `True`.  (I know this sounds convoluted and with overlapping variables - part of the desire to get tests running is to be able to refactor).

The code runs correctly in all environments, but when I try to run tests to assert that the fields have been updated, they fail.

(If I tweak the code to bypass the cluster and have the functions run in-memory then the tests pass.)

Given this, I'm assuming the issue lies in how I've written the tests, but I cannot diagnose the issue.

*tests_prepare_foo.py*

```
import time
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings, TransactionTestCase
from app.models import Foo

class CreateCourseTest(TransactionTestCase):
    reset_sequences = True    

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        cls.foo = Foo(status='draft',
                      prepared=False,
                      )
        cls.foo.save()

    def test_foo_prepared(self):
        self.foo.status = 'prepare'
        self.foo.save()
        time.sleep(15) # to allow the cluster to finish processing the request
        self.assertEquals(self.foo.prepared, True)
```

*models.py*

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from model_utils.fields import StatusField
from model_utils import Choices

class Foo(models.Model):

    ref = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,
                           editable=False,
                           )
    STATUS = Choices('draft', 'prepare', 'published', 'archived')
    status = StatusField(null=True,
                         blank=True,
                         )
    prepared = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def prepare_foo(self):
        """"
        ...
        do stuff
        """
```

*signals.py*

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django_q.tasks import async_task

from app.models import Foo 

@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def make_foo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs.get('created', False) and instance.status == 'prepare' and not instance.prepared:
        async_task('app.services.prepare_foo',
                   instance,
                   hook='app.hooks.check_foo_prepared',
                   )
```

*services.py*

```
def prepare_foo(foo):
    foo.prepare_foo()
```

*hooks.py*

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def check_foo_prepared(task):
    foo = task.args[0]
    if task.success:
        logger.info("Foo Prepared: Successful")
        foo.status = 'published'
        foo.prepared = True
        foo.save()
        logger.info("Foo Status: %s", foo.status)
        logger.info("Foo Prepared: %s", foo.prepared)
    else:
        logger.info("Foo Prepared: Unsuccessful")
        foo.status = 'draft'
        foo.save()
```

Finally - logs when the test is run with the cluster on:

*q-cluster server*

```
INFO:app.hooks:Foo Prepared: Successful
INFO:app.hooks: Foo Status: published
INFO:app.hooks: Foo Prepared: True
```

*django server*

```
h:m:s [Q] INFO Enqueued 1
F
======
FAIL
self.assertEquals(self.foo.prepared, True)
AssertionError: False !=  True
```

I think I'm either missing something obvious in my tests, or something really subtle, but I can't work out which.  I've tried setting the cluster to run synchronously (`sync=True`), and in my test reloading Foo just before the assertion:

```
self.foo.save()
time.sleep(15)
test_foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
self.assertEquals(test_foo.prepared, True)
```

But this also fails with

```
self.assertEquals(test_foo.prepared, True)
AssertionError: False !=  True
```

Which leads me to believe that the cluster is not updating the object under test (unlikely), or the assertion is being checked before the cluster has updated the object (more likely).

This is the first time I've written tests that require hand-offs to a cluster, so any pointers, suggestions gratefully received!